# Can I make new 'pch' figure in 'plot' function? (R)

Tags: r

I'm trying to write some R code for my study simulation.
For my code completion, I have to handle "plot(..., pch = 11)"

I want to make some new pch figure through some jpg files or png files.
(Train photo.jpeg, ....)

Could you help me? please..